# Downloading a file from the web to be attached to an outlook message sent from client

Tags: javascript, .net

Yes. I know most developers avoid this because the browser does not allow such hidden downloads, and ask the user if and where to save the file (Known web security issue).
And also I could not know when the download is over.

But

If my client realy insist that he will be able to click once on a web page an have an outlook window open and filled,containing an attachment. can I do so using my own customized browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a customized browser, yes. (If your client runs windows and has office installed...)

For example, create a .Net winform-program with a IE-browser-control in it.
Add hook to IE-control to get when user clicks a specific a-link.

Then perform a download of file from winform-program, use office-api/automation/3rdpart-control from winform-program to fire up a new mail and add attachment to the mail.

Comment: any idea how this hook should look like?

Comment: Sure. Have done similar things when I used the IE control as a backend for a mediaplayer.. I can add an example to this answer later. Im pretty busy tomorrow (going to see a Jean-Michelle-Jarre concert. ) But I'll add an example after that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can push a server side existent file into a local email window as attachment. It is not sure your client machine runs windows or has MS Outlook at all.

there are mailto link specifications to have urls made in a way that most of the Email clients will receive certain commands from the browser and act accordingly, for example as you can see here: [Mailto Parameters Test](http://www.csgnetwork.com/directmailtoparameters.html) try the link in the page and you will get a new email window in your default Email Client with To, CC, BCC, Body and subject prefilled.

There is nothing else you can do because you cannot embed file streams in such mailto url.